# What could cause an underground leak that happens every other day?

Tags: leak

We have a leak of just a few gallons coming up from the foundation in our garage and outside in the RV parking area. It runs for just a few minutes, then stops. It happens every other day, between  5:00-5:30 am. The water company didn't detect a leak and our water bill didn't go up either.

This has been going on 3 months. We drilled 2 seep holes, but it didn't change anything.

Could this be an underground stream?

Comment: The timing and amount matches quite closely to a toilet flush.  A few minutes and a few gallons.

Comment: Does this timing sync with your sprinkler system schedule? (assuming you have a sprinkler system)

Comment: @mblatz01 Or alternatively, could there be (fragments of) a disused sprinkler system that nobody told you about?

Comment: Try setting your alarm clock to 4:50 on a day when it's supposed to leak again, get up and close your main water shutoff. If there's suddenly no leak, you at least know the source is in your house.

Comment: Sewage leak? Is someone taking a shower from 5:00-5:30 am? It would explain the "few gallons" much more convincingly compared to a toilet being flushed.

Comment: NO way it's an underground river, timing is too consistent for that. Are you on septic or sewer?   Is there an odor to the leak? Are there neighbors nearby with a sprinkler system? do you have a sprinkler system? Leaks in those are not uncommon, often installed with class 200 PVC which is easily damaged.   I like @mblatz01 comment about the sprinkler system(s), as well at TooTea recommendation to turn off the water to your house and see if the leak stops.

Comment: It's possible, tho' less likely than scenarios in other comments, that there is a small, continuous leak which is filling an abscess somewhere, and coincidentally it overflows (siphons) on a 24-hour schedule.

Comment: Need pictures...

Comment: will try to shut off main before it leaks, doesn't run with sprinkler system.  no odor, water is clear.

Comment: Sprinkler, water softener, refrigerator ice maker, refrigerator defrost cycle.

Comment: Have you thought of calling Ghost Busters.  The amount and timing almost too odd, once every other day at same time.

Answer (score 5):

well we found the problem.  lady up the street had a broken sprinkler.  flooded into cable box and ran to our house.  husband fixed the sprinkler  now no more water.